# An example to show how to parameterize sql query to prevent sql injection attack

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

This is the sql query before parameterise. I was trying to parameterise the code to prevent sql injection attack. Bansi has helped me to work through this. His answer is ticked below

The below code is what we are going to parameterise.

```
$sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR details LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR category LIKE '%searchquery%' OR subcategory LIKE '%searchquery%' OR price LIKE '%searchquery%') ";
} 
require_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count >= 1){
    $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
```

and it should be changed to the code below as per bansi answer. the key part is as below

```
require_once ("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
$stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
$param = "%$searchquery%";
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $param, $param, $param, $param, $param);
$stmt->execute();
/* store result */
$stmt->store_result();
/* get the row count */
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($count >= 1) {
    $search_output = "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $product_name, $price);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", $id, $product_name, $price);
```

Comment: Looks like you need to escape your quotes properly (or use doubles) ex. `'\''` or `"'"` Also, this would be something that you should google first. I can say with great certainty that someone on the first SERP has asked about your exact problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the database code or prepared statements. It's misquoted strings. Placeholders don't belong in single quotes anyway.

Comment: please use a good IDE/Editor. makes your coding much easier.

Comment: sry, using notepad atm..will try ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code works and give you the result, but it doesn't show the result properly
how to modify the $search_output?

```
<?php

$search_output = "";

if (isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "") {
    $searchquery = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\/\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if ($_POST['filter1'] == "Products") {
        require_once ("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
        //syntax error string not quoted properly
        $stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
        $param = "%$searchquery%";
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $param , $param , $param , $param , $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $product_name, $price);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf("%s %s %s\n", $id, $product_name, $price);
            $search_output .= "
            <li><div class='product'>
            <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
            <span class='holder'>
            <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
            <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
            </a>
             <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
            </div>
            </li>

            ";
        }//While loop was not closed

    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    }
}
?>
```

you have 2 syntax errors. *Edited to fix bind statement and changed sql*

```
<?php

$search_output = "";

if (isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "") {
    $searchquery = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\/\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if ($_POST['filter1'] == "Products") {
        require_once ("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
        //syntax error string not quoted properly
        $stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
        $param = "%$searchquery%";
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $param , $param , $param , $param , $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($product_name, $price);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf("%s %s\n", $product_name, $price, $totalpoints);

            $search_output .= "
            <li><div class='product'>
            <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
            <span class='holder'>
            <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
            <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
            </a>
             <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
            </div>
            </li>

            ";
        }//While loop was not closed

    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    }
}
?>
```

also you need to bind all 5 parameters change the following line.

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', '%$searchquery%');
```

**Edit:**

```
$stmt->bind_result($product_name, $price);
```

should be the following if the third column is total points. It is impossible to know the column names when you are using `*` to `select`

```
$stmt->bind_result($product_name, $price, $totalpoints);
```

And

```
printf("%s %s\n", $product_name, $price, $totalpoints);
```

can be

```
printf("%s %s %s\n", $product_name, $price, $totalpoints);
```

OR Just

```
echo "$product_name $price $totalpoints\n";
```

to get the total use after executing the statement.

```
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

**Edit 2**
Check if this works added count also.

```
$search_output = "";

if (isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "") {
    $searchquery = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\/\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if ($_POST['filter1'] == "Products") {
        require_once ("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
        $stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
        $param = "%$searchquery%";
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $param, $param, $param, $param, $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        /* store result */
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* get the row count */
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($count >= 1) {
            $search_output = "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $product_name, $price);

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                printf("%s %s %s\n", $id, $product_name, $price);
                $search_output .= "
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
                <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>

                ";
            }
        } else {
            $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
        }

    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution says Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference also thanks

Comment: you should change the bind line. see @DevZer0's answer

Comment: changed but still no luck?

Comment: what is the error message now?

Comment: i copy and pasted your code but still say Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference, that's when i submit searchquery variable from my form  =(

Comment: changed bind, please check now.

Comment: thanks, that's a step forward...but my result not output properly...i want the $id,$product_name and $price
how do i change this`printf("%s %s\n",$id, $product_name, $price);`

Comment: and i found it doesn't display the number of total result as it should

Comment: opps..i think i place the thing at the wrong place..but anyway i think you can read it...the searchoutput doesn't pick up the variable? my product_name,link etc doesn't work

Comment: check if your table columns are `id, product_name, price` in that order. better you can specify columns in the `SELECT` like `SELECT id, product_name, price FROM ...` (please use the actual table field names)

Comment: haha, you are good..i have done exactly `id,product_name,price` instead of `*` and that show my result properly..ok now extra two things, first the `count` thing i integrated but it keep showing -1 as the result, second thing if there is no result it should echo my last sentence '0 result' but it is not echoed out. I didn't expect i can get this far thou, thanks mate

Comment: tried `$count = $stmt->num_rows` also -1

Comment: brilliant, i learnt alot today. thanks

Comment: just wanna say another thanks as your step to step guide basically has taught and enable me to build my entire website. Thanks! My very important guru on programming life

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your quotations in the prepared statement.
The correct way to do it would be to leave out the single quotes around the quotation marks. If you need to use quotes within quotes you can use double quotes within single quotes.

Here is the solution:

> $stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ');

Another option when making string like that is to concatenate strings together with .'s. like so:

> $string = $oldString. " hello";

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is you haven't parameter your query properly. you have prematurely terminated your string and inserted a `?` from the context of the language interpreter. This will obviously result in a syntax error.

insert your parameters without breaking the string.

```
->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category` LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
```

Now you have 5 parameters. You need to provide values for all 5 parameters as follows.

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', "%$searchquery%", "%$searchquery%", "%$searchquery%", "%$searchquery%", "%$searchquery%");
```

i also noticed that you had used single quotes (`'`) in your `%$searchquery%` variable. You will need to use double quotes `"` as single quotes will not expand your variable.

Comment: can i know the difference of "" and ''?

Comment: if you use `'`(single) to quote a string everything you put inside will be treated as literal string. but if you use `"`(double) php will try to parse all variables inside the string and replace with the value of the variable.

Comment: erm..i think i get some sense now..hopefully

Comment: erm..why sometime they put `' . $variable. '` or something like `$variableOutput .= ' blah blah blah ';`
why `'. .'` and why ` .=`?

Comment: assume `$variable='and';` so `'this ' . $variable . ' that'` will be `this and that` also `"this $variable that"` will be having same value. but `'this $variable that'` will be having value `this $variable that` (note the variable is not replaced)

Comment: thanks for your patient ..i think i am more clear now..has been confused and wasted a lot of time testing '' or ""